# Do you know any synonymous phrasal verbs or the like for 'bear down on'?

Tags: synonyms

What first comes to mind as far as I am concerned is 'close in on' , and that's not saying much. I've looked on every dictionary as well, but I have found nothing that conveys the precise meaning, as defined by oxford dictionary : 'move directly towards someone or something in a purposeful or intimidating manner.
Close in on suggest the two objects are both in motion to me, and in can also imply speed (the cheetah was closing in on the  antelope). In the case of Bear down on, one object is quasi motionless, and there's also the ' purposeful, intimidating manner, that the former fails to convey.  To my ear, it also implies a slower approach, prolonging the anxiety( ex: the huge ship looming in the distance was bearing down on us).

Comment: It might help if you explained why “bear down on” is no good for your purposes because it seems to mean exactly what you want it to mean.

Answer (score 3):

You could try, [***creep up on***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/creep+up+on)

> Advance slowly or stealthily, as in
>
> *The cat crept up on the bird*, or *Autumn is creeping up on us*.
>
> This expression is recorded in slightly different form- **creep in** or **creep on** -from the 15th century on. One of the Hymns to the Virgin and Christ (c. 1430) has *"Now age has cropen [crept] up on me ful stille."*

Source: The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms by Christine Ammer.

> *If there wasn't any wind and you were on a small boat and the bigger ship was [**creeping up on**](https://books.google.fr/books?id=W67rDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT88&lpg=PT88&dq=%22ship+was+creeping+up%22&source=bl&ots=4o2mVKuLXT&sig=uzIW1oW5ULsNN7w4ChDxgtz7jG4&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKwfmTubPWAhVJWBoKHZqIDRgQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22ship%20was%20creeping%20up%22&f=false) you, you were done for.*

Source: Storm: Dog Girl Meets the Pirates of the Median